# Count & Tabulate Matching Records by Month

Tags: sql, count, extract, multiple-conditions

Rookie needs a little help. Can someone provide a query to easily count and then tabulate by month records matching two conditions to avoid using clumsy repetitive code like this...

```
SELECT 
SUM( CASE  
    WHEN extract( YEAR FROM  `date` ) =  "2017" 
    AND extract( MONTH FROM  `date` ) =  "07"
    AND  `conditionA` =  "A" 
    AND  `conditionB` =  "B" 
    THEN 1 else 0 END ) 
AS 2017_07

SUM( CASE  
    WHEN extract( YEAR FROM  `date` ) =  "2017" 
    AND extract( MONTH FROM  `date` ) =  "08"
    AND  `conditionA` =  "A" 
    AND  `conditionB` =  "B" 
    THEN 1 else 0 END ) 
AS 2017_08

SUM( CASE  
    WHEN extract( YEAR FROM  `date` ) =  "2017" 
    AND extract( MONTH FROM  `date` ) =  "09"
    AND  `conditionA` =  "A" 
    AND  `conditionB` =  "B" 
    THEN 1 else 0 END ) 
AS 2017_09

FROM  `datatable`
```

Comment: please take a look at this  link(https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to know more on how to improve the question and dont post images

Comment: Thanks. I'm all for asking better questions but need some clarification as to what I should have done differently. My question seems pretty concise and I posted a formatted query. I received an immediate, exact solution to the problem, basic as it was. Are you suggesting I should have posted table data for something this simple?

Comment: if you can take a look at the link i posted,it helps you..you didnt posted any table data,expected result,current result

Answer (score 2):

Put the data into rows, not columns:

```
SELECT extract( YEAR FROM  `date` ) as yyyy, extract( MONTH FROM  `date` ) as mm,
       COUNT(*)
FROM datatable
WHERE `conditionA` =  'A' AND  `conditionB` =  'B'
GROUP BY extract( YEAR FROM  `date` ), extract( MONTH FROM  `date` )
ORDER BY yyyy, mm ;
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!